# Django New Install, Apache >2.4, 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, django, apache, http-status-code-403

Have looked all over the net, and am getting some conflicting help.  django.wsgi is no longer in the latest version, correct?  it is replaced by wsgi.py?

This is my virtual host entry:

```
<VirtualHost myip:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  ServerName  mydomain
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django/djcode/emailer/emailer/wsgi.py
<Directory /home/django/djcode/emailer/emailer>
<Files wsgi.py>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

No startup http errors, after visiting page, this is apache error log:

```
[Thu Apr 03 19:16:49 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.6.6 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_wsgi/3.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 03 19:17:10 2014] [error] [client myip] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
[Thu Apr 03 19:17:11 2014] [error] [client myip] (13)Permission denied: access to /favicon.ico denied
```

Have been stuck on this issue for a little over an hour, so thought I'd finally ask.

Thanks!

Comment: also, do any permission changes need to be in my django home directory? (since its not in /var/www), didn't see any mention of that.

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that `Order deny,allow` & `Allow from all` are no longer used in Apache 2.4. You'll need to change this to `Require all granted`. See [this Apache 2.2 -> 2.4 upgrade article](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) for more info.

Also, your error log says Apache 2.2.15, not apache 2.15, so are you sure your Apache 2.4 install/upgrade worked? If you're still on Apache 2.2.15 then my answer is not applicable.